# regex cleaning html textarea content except for some attributes

Tags: php, regex, textarea

as usually a website user copies and pastes text from Word or other rte,  I use this line of code in PHP to clean the user's typed text content of a text area:

```
$text= preg_replace('/style=\"[^\"]*/', '', $text);
```

That line deletes all the styles from the html tags, without deleting the tags themselves, so I can style them the appropriate way through my CSS file.
Now I need to keep a `style="background:#99ff99;"` valid.
This a style that I myself add to the text.
How can I tell the regex to not consider `background:#99ff99` when cleaning all the tags?
Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

one solution might include using [preg_replace_callback($pattern,$callback,$subject,...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Something like that should work:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/style=\"[^\"]*/',
    function ($matches) {
        return ($matches[0] == 'style="background:#99ff99;"'?$matches[0]:'');
    },
    $text
);
```

Comment: Hi,thank you.It seems that you forgot a comma between the path and the callback fn. By the way, it didn't work for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the pattern, not the path

Comment: I have not. I just edited the example from the php manual with your pattern. I will check my answer asap.